# How to remove one data from shiny when another is uploaded

Tags: r, shiny, upload, reactive-programming

To illustrate my problem through minimal example, Let's consider the below code (which serves as fully reproducible example).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
  numericInput("n", "Rows", value = 5, min = 1, step = 1),
  tableOutput("head"),
  fileInput("upload2", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
  numericInput("n2", "Rows", value = 5, min = 1, step = 1),
  tableOutput("head2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    switch(ext,
           csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ","),
           tsv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = "\t"),
           validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
    )
  })
  
  output$head <- renderTable({
    head(data(), input$n)
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    
    req(input$upload2)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload2$name)
    switch(ext,
           csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload2$datapath, delim = ","),
           tsv = vroom::vroom(input$upload2$datapath, delim = "\t"),
           validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
    )
  })
  
  output$head2 <- renderTable({
    tail(data2(), input$n2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app asks user to upload a dataset, then asks number of rows and displays `head()` of that uploaded data.  If user uploads another dataset, similarly it's `tail` is displayed.

Now my requirement is that whenever shiny app user uploads `data2` for displaying bottom rows, the `data` for top/head rows should be removed from environment alongwith it's `head` info; and vice versa.

I have tried many methods like using `observeEvent`, `eventReactive`, etc. but I am unable to do.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
  numericInput("n", "Rows", value = 5, min = 1, step = 1),
  tableOutput("head"),
  fileInput("upload2", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
  numericInput("n2", "Rows", value = 5, min = 1, step = 1),
  tableOutput("head2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  data2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    new_data <- switch(ext,
                       csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ","),
                       tsv = vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = "\t"),
                       validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
    )
    data(new_data)
    data2(NULL)  
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$upload2, {
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload2$name)
    new_data <- switch(ext,
                       csv = vroom::vroom(input$upload2$datapath, delim = ","),
                       tsv = vroom::vroom(input$upload2$datapath, delim = "\t"),
                       validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
    )
    data2(new_data)
    data(NULL)
  })
  
  output$head <- renderTable({
    req(data())
    head(data(), input$n)
  })
  
  output$head2 <- renderTable({
    req(data2())
    tail(data2(), input$n2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly.  Thanks.  While I already accepted and upvoted, I was earlier thinking that whether the session argument (rarely used) of server function can be used here?